# How to find prev and next id record from table

Tags: mysql

How to know prev id value and next id value  from a table where id is given ?

like ia have id=5 for a recod in table then i want to know the prev id value and next id value

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is an auto-increment INT field,

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id < 5 ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id > 5 ORDER by ID ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like...

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS previous
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id < 5;
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS next
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id > 5;
```

would get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ( SELECT min(id) FROM table WHERE id > id )
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ( SELECT max(id) FROM table WHERE id < id )
```